# Flutter Language Translation

Tags: flutter

I am making an application in flutter, the data in the application is firebase, I need to add 27 languages to the application.There is also an web admin panel in the application.Adding data from admin panel.I use Getx

How can I translate the data coming from Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conventional approach in software development is to have static texts translated in different files, one file per language.

In the case of Flutter this is done using .arb files, see [the documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization) for how to do it.